# Answer doesn't make sense when doing substitution in multiple integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, jacobian

The following transformation is given: u= x-y and v= x+y. I was then told to evaluate $\int \int \frac{x-y}{(x+y)^2}dA$ where R is the square with vertices $(0,2), (1,1), (2,2), (1,3)$. When I converted the coordinates to (u,v), I got :$(-2,2), (0,2), (0,4), (-2,4)$ respectively. I found my jacobian as 1/2. I then setup my integral as $\frac{1}{2}\int_{-2}^{0}\int_{2}^{4}\frac{u}{v^2}dvdu$. When I evaluated it, I got $-\frac{1}{4}$. I am confused because I thought area could not be negative. Is this correct?

Comment: An integral can be thought of as a *signed* area (or volume); area (or volume) is positive, but the integral could be negative; in fact, the integrand $(x-y)/(x+y)^2\le0$ in $A$

Comment: Does that mean +1/4 is the correct answer because the graph is above the x-axis?

Comment: Your answer is correct

Comment: Did you mean $\int\int$ where you typed $\int\int\int$?

Comment: yeah i meant to put 2 integrals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is correct.  Area (or volume) is positive, but an integral can be thought of as a signed area (or volume) and thus negative.   In fact, the integrand $(x-y)/(x+y)^2\le0$ in $R$, since $x\le y$ and $(x+y)^2\ge0$.

The given integral could also be computed without a transformation of coordinates as follows:

$$\int_0^1\int_{2-x}^{2+x} \dfrac {x-y}{(x+y)^2} dydx + \int_1^2\int_{x}^{4-x} \dfrac {x-y}{(x+y)^2} dydx=\left(\frac12-\ln2\right)+\left(\ln2-\frac34\right)=-\frac14.$$

Comment: $$\int_0^1\int_{2-x}^{2+x} \dfrac {x-y}{(x+y)^2} dydx  = \int_0^1\int_{2-x}^{2+x}\dfrac{-(x+y)+2x}{(x+y)^2}dydx=\int_0^1\int_{2-x}^{2+x}\left(\dfrac{-1}{x+y}+\dfrac{2x}{(x+y)^2}\right)dydx $$ $$=\int_0^1 \left[-\ln(x+y)-2\dfrac x{x+y}\right]\mid_{2-x}^{2+x} dx=\int_0^1\left(-\ln(1+x)-\dfrac x{x+1}+x\right)dx =\int_0^1\left(-\ln(1+x)-\dfrac1{x+1}-1\right)dx                  =-(1+x)\ln(1+x)+(1+x)+\ln(x+1)-x+\frac12x^2|_0^1$$ $$=-2\ln2+1+\ln2-1+\frac12=           \left(\frac12-\ln2\right) $$